# compare a single value against a list of values stored in a cursor in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: database, plsql, list-comparison

I want to execute an insert statement if the `VALUE` I got is greater than every value in the cursor. Please look at following:

I got a pretty standard cursor which holds a list of date values:

```
set REF_CUR cursor for select BIRTHDAY from PEOPLE_TABLE where school='middle';
IF VALUE>ALL(REF_CUR)
   insert something into something;
END IF;
```

SO I know that this cursor only holds a single column `BIRTHDAY` with many rows WHICH I want to know if all of them are bigger than the `VALUE`, I cannot make that `ALL` thingy work.

Comment: Values are not stored in a cursor. A cursor is a specification of what rows to fetch - it has to be opened and fetched from by some client.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wont succeed in using `ALL` function this way, probably you get the following error:

> PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column '>ALL' may be used inside a SQL statement only

But you don't need it. I would recommend you to use `max` function:

```
select max(BIRTHDAY)
  into l_max_birthday 
  from PEOPLE_TABLE 
 where school='middle';
if VALUE > l_max_birthday then
  insert something into something;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in one `insert ... select ...` statement:

```
insert into something (...)
select <some values>
  from PEOPLE_TABLE 
 where school = 'middle'
having VALUE > max(BIRTHDAY);
```

If `VALUE` more than maximum value of `BIRTHDAY` column, this `SELECT` statement returns 1 row, which will be immediately inserted. If not, query returns 0 rows and 0 rows will be inserted.

`<some values>` could be static values or variables, not only columns of `PEOPLE_TABLE`.

The similar technique allows you to insert several rows if you need.